# How does a queue solve the thread race problem?

Tags: multithreading, race-condition, multitasking

I saw that there are many ways in order to avoid race conditions when tackling with multithreading, but the most common are mutexes and queues. I cannot understand how a queue could make an application thread safe as long as the threads may populate the queue in a chaotic order.

Comment: It's not as if you can magically make your entire application thread safe by putting a queue in it.  But using a queue *that is itself designed in a thread safe manner* can provide a good way for threads to communicate with each other.  It's true, unless you do more work you don't get any guarantees about the order in which elements are inserted in the queue, but you do get assurance that every element you insert does actually make it into the queue and eventually get processed.  A non-thread-safe structure risks having elements silently dropped, or corrupted, or worse.

Comment: How does a thread safe queue works? What is the mechanism behind the scenes? Is it a queue service with mutexes?

Comment: That's a different and broader question.  The simplest way is with a mutex associated with the queue, that each thread locks when either adding or removing from the queue.  There are also [lock-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) queue algorithms that can avoid a mutex by making appropriate use of atomic primitives and careful attention to memory ordering.  The details can be very subtle, and are too broad for an SO answer - takes more like a textbook or at least a textbook chapter.

Comment: You are speaking far too generally and non-specifically.  Two threads accessing the same data in an unsynchronized manner may result in a race condition.  You perhaps have a hidden assumption that this queue is a thread-safe data structure.  Your question is not really well defined.  Meanwhile, just check out [What is a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition)

Comment: @Wyck I do not agree. It is sound to assume he is not talking about a buggy multiple writer single reader queue, but one which works. Then, it is indeed impossible to rely on some notion of "what happened first", if N writers in N threads post messages at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot understand how a queue could make an application thread safe as long as the threads may populate the queue in a chaotic order.

First of all, let's get "thread safe" out of the way. "Thread safety"  really only should be used to describe the *components* (functions, modules, classes, libraries, etc.) that can be used to build an application.

A component is thread-safe if it guarantees to behave in some useful and well documented way when it is concurrently used by more than one thread. Since you're talking about queues, here's what you might expect from a thread-safe queue:

1. Every item that is `put()` into the queue eventually can be `take()`en from the queue.
2. No item can ever be `take()`en that was not `put()`.
3. **IF** the program puts two items into the queue in a certain order, then they will be `take()`en in the same order,

BUT,

4. If the program allows concurrent `put()` calls to the queue, then the queue cannot guarantee the order in which those items actually will appear in the queue.

"Thread safety" doesn't really apply to applications because the user of an application cannot choose whether to use it in a multi-threaded way or in a single-threaded way. That choice is baked-in by the application author. An application either is *correct* (it works as expected) or else it isn't.

So, let's re-state your question:

> I cannot understand how a queue could make an application *correct* as long as the threads may populate the queue in a chaotic order.

It can't. If the application depends on objects being `put()` into a queue in some particular order, then it is the application programmer's responsibility to ensure that the `put()` calls do not overlap. If the calls are allowed to overlap, there is no way that the queue could possibly know which order the application programmer *intended* for the items to go in to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

In a concurrent system, (thread priorities aside), the operating systems scheduler decides, which of the currently runnable threads it schedules next on the (multiple) CPU cores. It tries to be "fair" as to not starve some unfortunate thread, while favoring others. In realtime operating systems (e.g. QNX), of course, there is a lot more fineprint, adding to this simple concept.

As such, in such a system, it impossible to reason about "who came first", as from the point of view of the application, the scheduler decisions appear random (but fair).

So, if someone tried to make a "better" queue, they might think of using a priority queue instead and use a timestamp for the ordering of the queues contents. But - as each thread obtains a timestamp (assuming high enough resolution anyway), it is yet again just "random" from the point of view of the application, which of the threads will come first.

Which - kind of is the proof, that queue or not - this problem cannot be solved.

It is - by the way, the same with a cpu which has N interrupt sources, which change their logical level all at once. Either the hardware prioritizes or the order in which those interrupts get processed depends on the interrupt architecture (interrupt vectors for each interrupt or a single interrupt vector with software dispatch?), line noise, variability in the electrical characteristics of each input etc.

How to work around this? Instead of having strict ordering (x came before y), you need to have some ternary approach `(x, [y,z,t], u)`, where - according to your applications requirements, you have a notion of "simultaneity". I.e. x came first, then y,z,t simultaneously (within a defined time interval), then u.

Also, having your threads arranged in form of an acyclic directed graph, like little steps in an assembly line instead of some events forming some feedback loop helps avoiding "higher order" race conditions.

Just like in the www, having idempotent requests to a worker thread also helps. `(a,b) -> ((a,b),c)` Returning the question with the answer is another trick to avoid confusion.